# What will happen with unix timestamp after 2038

Tags: unix, timestamp

Okay so I've figured out why timestamps can't go over 2038 because of the 32 bit integers, that's cool. But I couldn't help but wonder what will be done to overcome this problem. I can't seem to find a straight answer to that question anywhere and it's bugging me so bad. Like if they introduce 64 bit timestamps are we gonna have to refactor our systems? Or if they decide to split timestamps into chunks like 1970-2038, 2038-2076 etc.. ?

Comment: This is so called UNIX-Millenium problem... But this is not the right forum

Comment: One possibility would be to use 64bit numbers...